# How to "re-display" the information suppresses by "display: none;" in <style>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is what I have, and what I would like to accomplish:

I have a `<div id=”object”>` element with number of `<div>`s below it. These `<div>`s elements are: one image and number of other elements (descriptions, button).

When I open a page, the css `<style>` suppress display of all but image elements:

```
    <style id=”noDisp”>
        #object .oName,
        #object .oDescription,
        …  ,
        #object .oButton {
            display: none;
        {
    </style>
```

I also have a `<button>` element. I would like to “re-display” all information which has not been displayed, using `“onclick=”`.

Is it possible? Please advise!

Comment: do you have control over <style> contents? You're better off using classes, so you can do something like `#object.hidden .oButton { display: none }`. Then toggle with `onclick="document.querySelector('#object').classList.toggle('hidden')"`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display an element which has css display none then jquery to display it on click e.g:

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(){
  $("#elementId").css("display", "block");
});
```

To use class as selector e.g:

```
$(".class").css("display", "block");
```

Comment: I can't see a `jQuery` tag on the question.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, You can do that by creating another style class and inherit it on high priority where you want to override the previous class.